# Karate: runners class with JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, karate, junit5

sorry for the naive question:
What are the references to "sample" and "tags" in the example documentation that explains the configuration of tests with Junit5?
Are these features?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it tries to be more concise instead of `sample.feature` etc.

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#junit-5